# Is there a comprehensive list of all of the out of the box web parts that are connectable?

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

There is very little information available on connecting web parts on a web part page. This seems to be too advanced a topic for most of the end user resources. On the other hand, it's not a developer or IT Pro topic either.

Here are the resources I've checked:
 - The Bill English's "SharePoint Administrator's Companion" and the "SharePoint 2007 User's Guide" by Seth Bates both have one page on the topic. Rob Bogues' book has nothing I can find.
 - Office Online, [Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100241051033.aspx) is not complete.

I want a comprehensive list of all of the out of the box web parts that are connectable and under which exact scenarios.

Comment: Are you waiting for the bounty? I don't see the option to add one yet.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the edit. You're right. That is less subjective. And more descriptive. Any ideas on the answer?

Comment: Sorry no and no time to find out either! But the way I would find out (being a dev) is use a tool to find all web parts in the SharePoint DLLs that implement the connectable interfaces.

Comment: @Alex that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...did a little quick digging, found some interesting resources:

- A nice write up of the mechanics of how they work. Not completely end user, but not exactly dev-oriented either - [MSDN Web Part Connection Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178187.aspx)
- A hands on walk through of setting up a connection from the SharePoint Designer Team blog - [Creating Master-Detail views with Web Part connection](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/08/22/creating-master-detail-views-with-web-part-connections-using-flickr-services-as-a-data-source.aspx)

I found several other posts that may be what you're looking for, but they seemed a little more specific. Here's what I used to do the search: [SearchforSharePoint.com](http://searchforsharepoint.com/default.aspx?cx=004914653578476231099%3Aoueg30i%5Fyh0&q=web+part+connections&sa=Search&cof=FORID%3A9#1130)

John

Comment: Hi John, those are both good articles, but don't you think there should be something better? I've wondered about this question from the very first time connections were demonstrated to me by a SharePoint MVP 4 years ago. Why doesn't someone explain it better?